# A Leadership Vacuum: Please Step Up

Tags: discusión, moderación

For the last several weeks, I have been seeking a third moderator for this site. Currently, there are only two active moderators: Joze and Flimzy, both of whom have done an excellent job of keeping Spanish.SE ticking!

However, they do need one more moderator, and I'm having trouble finding the right person.

So, I am turning to the community and issuing a call to arms. **This community needs people to lead it!** Moderation is about accepting edits and handling flags, yes, but it's also about serving as a role model to the community. It's about helping shape the site, policy-wise and scope-wise, into something that can -- nay, will! -- be truly successful, valuable, and *makes the internet better!*

This may seem like a tall order, but I am confident that there is someone who is dedicated to this site enough that he or she wants to take on the position. Furthermore, *you would not be going at it alone*. Moderators work as a *team* to address issues, move the site forward, and clarify the breadth of the site itself. It is a privilege (and a joy!) to be able to look at a community and know you've had a direct hand in building it.

I'll stress this much: this is a *voluntary* activity. If you opt to step in and then find yourself overwhelmed by Real Life or work or some such, you're free to leave or take a leave of absence, but you'd need to let the Community Managers and your fellow moderators know.

This site needs someone willing to stand up and say, "I want to make this place better!" If you're that person, *please say so!* We'd love to have you. :D

Comment: If you choose to volunteer, please mention if you're a native speaker. :)

Comment: Besides a _willing heart_, are there any specific requirements (e.g. certain ammount of rep or number of edits, etc.) that would be required to be eligible for the position? :)

Comment: @Miguel Nope! A willing heart is all we need! Moderating a beta site is done best when the team of people in charge represent different ideas and are willing to discuss contentious issues, if they arise.

Comment: It's been a week and no one wants in? :(

Comment: I'm a native Spanish speaker, but, I like to help on my spare time, I don't know about taking roles and responsibilities that I may not be able to full fill

Answer (score 1):

I would be willing to volunteer as a moderator if there is still a need.

- I have a significant amount of experience with other SE sites, and I am quite active on the SO meta, so I am familiar with the general culture and expectations of SE sites.
- On SO in particular, I have achieved the Deputy and Copy Editor badges; I am adept at identifying and (where possible) fixing content that needs improvement.
- I was also a moderator for a couple of years on [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/profile/104051/pbmods/), so I have experience working with a team of moderators and administrators to resolve issues and guide community developments.
- Being in the process of learning Spanish myself in preparation for an upcoming move to Costa Rica, I am also very interested in participating in and furthering the growth and development of the Spanish SE site, as it is one of the best resources I have found for getting a better understanding of regional/cultural differences and slang/expressions.

Now, my shining credentials aside, there are a few weaknesses that I would need to work on to get up to snuff:

- I have not been particularly active on the Spanish SE meta site, but my participation here will increase as I take on a more active role on the site.
- I have absolutely zero experience with SE chats, so that will all be very new to me.
- Also, my time is somewhat limited; the maximum amount of time I would be able to commit to is 8 hours per week.

[image: profile for Phoenix on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help, as well as your candid evaluation of your credentials!

Answer (score 1):

I have not discussed this with him at all, so he may not be interested, but I would like to nominate for possible consideration:

### [JoulSauron](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/106/joulsauron)

Although a relatively new member (48 days as of this writing) of our community, and indeed to SE as a whole, he is very active, both on the main site, and in meta discussions.  I have been very pleased with his contributions to the site, and I believe he has a good feel for how the site ought to work. He has had some valuable ideas regarding the possible direction of this site.

He's also a native Spanish speaker (I'm assuming, based on his location, and his numerous posts).

Comment: Thank you so much for considering me :P I was actually considering this for I while, but I didn't want to commit myself to being a moderator as recently I'm being too busy. However, according to my participation, I think I would be able to deal with it.
I'm Spaniard, yes, so no problem about Spanish :D So my decision is that if you people finally see that I'm eligible, I'm open for further discussion :)